# Laravel 5.6 register user with role

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hello i was following this tutorial

https://www.5balloons.info/user-role-based-authentication-and-access-control-in-laravel/#comment-1889

i done everything ok and add some rules, a custom error page, and only admin can register new users.  in the /admin view i can see all users register and the admin can delete this users.

i need two more roles, for users to see especific views, and i’m trying define the role in the register form 
so the admin can define who can see the a specific page.
one role for executive user and one for premium user.

i was able to do that, but only by adding the relation in the 
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZKhf.png)  role_user table

any idea how to get this done by the register form? without entering in the database table

Comment: Are you asking how to add a role when the user is registered?

Comment: yes, i need to add the role in the register form, so when i register a user  i can make the relation

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you're using a Blade template. Use the following to add a drop down for the Role select.

```
<select name="role">
@foreach ( $roles as $role )
  <option value="${{role->id}}">{{ $role->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

You'll need to provide your currently available Roles, from your Role Model (ha), to the view. This can be done in your controller when rendering the view.

```
// Part of your controller
$roles = Role::all();
return view('your-view', [ 'roles' => $roles ]);
```

The key part here is `return view('your-view', [ 'roles' => $roles ])`. The second parameter in the `view` function is data to be passed to the view itself. See [the Blade docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data) for more info.

When you submit your form you can "attach" the role to your user model after it has been saved.

```
$user = new User();
// Assign user info here
$user->save();
$user->roles()->attach($request->role);
```

- `->roles()` is the model that belongs to User that we want to attach to.
- `->attach($request->role)` - `$request->role` is the ID of the Role we want to attach to the newly created User.

You can [read more in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) about attaching and assigning various relationships to others.

Answer (score 1):

[`see this the path`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNW6o.png)

this the path of registration form

```
vendor > laravel > framework > src >Illuminate >Foundation > Auth > RegistersUsers.php
```

this is my code #example
and this is the controller of registration form

```
  /**
 * Show the application registration form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    $show = model_rolepath::all();
    return view('auth.register')->with('roles',$show);
}
```

and this is my blade

```
 <div class="input-group mb-3 {{ $errors->has('role') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <select type="text" class="form-control"  value="{{ old('role') }}" required autofocus id="role" name="role" placeholder="Role">
      @foreach($roles as $key=>$role)
          <option value="{{$role->rolepath}}">{{ $role->rolepath }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
      @if ($errors->has('role'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('role') }}</strong>
        </span>
      @endif
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text">
          <span class="fas fa-tasks"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Customise the registration form:**

Generate the authentication scaffolding which comes bundled with Laravel.

`php artisan make:auth`

Now that we have added the `role` column to our User model we also need to add the input for the roles in our view so add the select tag input to `resources/views/auth/register.blade.php` registration form.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="role" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Role</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select name="role" class="form-control" >
            <option value="admin">Admin</option>
            <option value="agent">Agent</option>
            <option value="customer">Customer</option>
        </select> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**Customise User model and RegisterController:**

Add the role column to `fillable` attribute on the User Model so that we can make use of the `create()` method in Register Controller.

```
//User.php
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','role',
];
```

Now customize `RegisterController.php` which is in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth` directory to include our `role` input when creating a new user.

Add a validation rule for the `role` field:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'role' => 'required|in:admin,agent,customer', //validate role input
    ]);
}
```

Add role field to the `create()` method:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'role' => $data['role'],
    ]);
}
```

Now you should be able to register users with different roles. We’ll create at least one user per each role, and we will move on to implementing the access control logic.

**Set-up middlewares:**

[Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware) provides a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering our application. For example, Laravel includes an `auth` middleware that verifies the user of your application is logged-in.

We will create middlewares for each of our roles.

```
php artisan make:middleware Admin
php artisan make:middleware Agent
php artisan make:middleware Customer
```

Add the following code to respective middlewares which are in `app/Http/Middleware` folder:

```
use Auth; //at the top

function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
        return $next($request);
    }
    elseif (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'agent') {
        return redirect('/agent');
    }
    else {
        return redirect('/customer');
    }
}
```

**Agent.php**

```
use Auth; //at the top

function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'agent') {
        return $next($request);
    }
    elseif (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'customer') {
        return redirect('/customer');
    }
    else {
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
}
```

**Customer.php**

```
use Auth; //at the top

function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'customer') {
        return $next($request);
    }
    elseif (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'agent') {
        return redirect('/agent');
    }
    else {
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
}
```

Now let’s register our middleware with Laravel. Add the middleware classes to `$routeMiddleware` property located in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ...
    'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Admin',
    'agent' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Agent',
    'customer' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Customer',
];
```

Now you can apply these middlewares to routes or to the controller itself:

**web.php:**

```
Route::get('/admin', function(){
    echo "Hello Admin";
})->middleware('admin');

Route::get('/agent', function(){
    echo "Hello Agent";
})->middleware('agent');

Route::get('/customer', function(){
    echo "Hello Customer";
})->middleware('customer');
```

Or you can specify a middleware in a controller’s constructor, like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');  
    $this->middleware('admin');
}
```

**Redirect User After Log-in:**

If you use Laravel’s default login setup, you may want to redirect the user to his role specific page after he logs in. and you can do that by overriding the `redirectTo()` method in your LoginController.php. Make sure you remove the `$redirectTo` property from your `LoginController.php`.

**Add this to your `LoginController.php:`**

```
protected function redirectTo( ) {
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'customer') {
        return('/customer');
    }
    elseif (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'agent') {
        return('/agent');
    }
    else {
        return('/admin');
    }
}
```

This solution was provided by @kerneldev  more info on [github](https://github.com/SapneshNaik/laravel_role_based_access_control)